# Oracle Unique Key - get PK or RowID

Tags: oracle, primary-key, unique-key

Is it possible to catch the master key or the record rowID that triggered the duplication exception?

table1 have PK: col1 and Unique1: col2

e.g.

```
begin
  insert into table1(col1, col2, col3)
  values (1, 2, 3);
exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
    --- here, can you somehow indicate either PK or ROWID of the record that generated the exception of uniqueness?
  e.g.
  update table1 set 
    col3 = 100
  where rowid = "GETROWID" or col1 = "GETPK";
end;
```

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: How many indexes do you have on your table? Which column(s)?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's about detecting which record already exists... I suppose there's no such mechanism, but that's what I wanted to ask... But the fact is that if there are many unique indices, there may be a lot of them in danger, then it will not be one ROWID but many...

Comment: It does matter. The reason I asked is that you could just query your table to find matching records causing the exception, then handle it from there. I think that's going to be your only option.

Comment: That I can ask the database is clear, but I thought there was a way to get "automatically"

Answer (score 2):

In "normal" code you don't use constants to insert values; you'd normally have the value in a variable so your code would look more like:

```
DECLARE
  strVar1    TABLE1%TYPE;
  nVar2      NUMBER;
  nVar3      NUMBER;
begin
  SELECT s1, n2, n3
    INTO strVar1, nVar2, nVar3
    FROM SOME_TABLE;

  insert into table1(col1, col2, col3)
    values (strVar1, nVar2, nVar3);
exception
  when dup_val_on_index then
    update table1
      set col3 = 100
      where col1 = strVar1;
end;
```

But a better idea is to avoid the exception in the first place by using a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 t1
  USING (SELECT S1, N2, N3
           FROM SOME_TABLE) s
    ON (t1.COL1 = s.S1)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET COL3 = 100
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (COL1, COL2, COl3)
    VALUES (s.S1, s.N2, s.N3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The LOG ERRORS INTO could help here. You have to prepare an error table before using this clause:

```
begin
  dbms_errlog.create_error_log('table1');
end;
```

That will create err$_table1 table. Now run the insert using additional feature

```
insert into table1(col1, col2, col3) values (1, 2, 3)
log errors into err$_table1 ('some_tag_to_look_for') reject limit unlimited;
```

Querying the err$_table1 with
    select * from err$_table1;

won't give you the rowid (it gets filled for updates and deletes only) but you'll get the exact column values causing the error and the index violated.

If that is not enough you can find the indexed columns here

```
select * from all_ind_columns where owner='OWNER_NAME_from_error_table' and index_name = 'Name_from_err_table';
```

Thus you'll know which column(s) in the destination table already has the value you are trying to insert --> this is how you'll find the rowid or whatever you need